# Show users that liked a post on django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

Well, I have one of the functions of my project is to give likes to posts and when that is done the users that liked the post are suposed to apear next to the like count, the problem is that the users dont appear for some reason. I think that error is in the models, I think it should have a definition to show the users or something like that.

views.py

```
    def like_post(request):
        user = request.user
        if request.method == 'POST':
          post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
          post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
          if user in post_obj.liked.all():
            post_obj.liked.remove(user)
          else:
            post_obj.liked.add(user)
          like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(author=user, post_id=post_id)
          if not created:
            if like.value == 'Like':
              like.value == 'Unlike'
            else:
              like.value = 'Like'

          like.save()
        return redirect('imagelist')

    def imagelist(request):
        images = Post.objects.all()
        context2 = {
            "images": images,
        }
        return render(request, 'imagelist.html', context2)
```

Models.py

```
    class Like(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, default='Like', max_length=10)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.post)

    class Post(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        posti = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images', null=True, blank="True")
        video = models.FileField(upload_to='media/images', null=True, blank="True")
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='imageuser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='username')
        liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name='liked')
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.tittle)

        @property
        def num_likes(self):
            return self.liked.all().count()
```

imagelist.html

```
    <strong>{{ image.liked.user }}</strong>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a loop for this like that:

```
{% for user in image.liked.all %}
 {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you! your code worked, can you please explain to me why did that work?

Comment: Of course, when you use `image.liked.user` directly, it returned None and  no data is displayed. Because, your `liked` field returned a queryset. This queryset consists of User objects. So there isn't `user` field. You must access the objects with loop and after that, you can access the fields of user.